# Use REGEXP in MySQL to match keywords for search engine in random order

Tags: mysql, regex, random, expression

I'm trying to use a regular expression to match a user entered search string to a title of an entry in my MySQL database.

For example I have the following rows in a table in my databse:

```
id   title
1    IM2 - Article 3 Funky Business
2    IM2 - Article 4 There's no Business That's not Show Business
3    IM2 - There's no Business That's not Show Business
4    CO4 - Life's a business
```

When a user searches for "IM Article Business", the following query will be executed (spaces are replaced by "(.*)" using str_replace):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE title REGEXP 'IM(.*)Article(.*)Business'
```

This will return the first 2 rows.

Now, I want it to show the same results when a user uses the same words, but in another order, for example: "Business IM Article". The results MUST contain all words entered, only the order of how the words are entered shouldn't matter.

I couldn't figure out how to do it in any way and hoped regular expressions would be the answer. I've never used them before, so does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks,
Pascal

Comment: An interesting example of the value of using the right tool for the job. Good choice to go back to the wildcard. Even more than other contexts, SQL just isn't a good place to "try things until something works". But it is a good place to try things to understand how they work and where they are appropriate. SQL is a life-long learning experience.

Comment: Very good point about SQL not being a "try until works" place. I've definitely noticed myself treating it that way, but never really explicitly thought about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't something regular expressions are great at. Fortunately, it's something SQL is pretty good at. (I'm going to not use mysql's regexp keyword, which I didn't even knew existed, and instead use the SQL standard "%" glob matching.)

`select * from mytable where title like '%IM%' and title like '%Article%' and title like '%Business%'`

Now `title` has to contain all three strings, but you haven't specified an order. Exactly what you want.

Comment: I already tried this and it wouldn't work, but for some strange reason, when I just tried it again, it worked! So simple haha. Thanks!

Comment: Good answer - both knowledge and wisdom.

Comment: The: `title ='%abc%'` syntax didn't work for me, but: `title LIKE '%abc%'` did. So did: `title REGEXP 'abc'` (MySQL Rev 5.0.81)

Comment: oh right! I knew '=' felt wrong typing it, but I couldn't think why.